# In python, how to shift and fill with a specific values for all the shifted rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, fill, shift

I have a following dataframe.

```
y = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10,1), dtype = 'bool'), columns = ['A'])
y.iloc[[3,5], 0] = True

      A
0  False
1  False
2  False
3   True
4  False
5   True
6  False
7  False
8  False
9  False
```

And I want to make 'True' for the next three rows from where 'True' is found in the above dataframe. The expected results is shown in the below.

```
       A
0  False
1  False
2  False
3   True
4   True
5   True
6   True
7   True
8  False
9  False
```

I can do that in the following way, but I wonder if there is a smarter way to do so.

```
y['B'] = y['A'].shift()
y['C'] = y['B'].shift()
y['D'] = y.any(axis = 1)

y['A'] = y['D']
y = y['A']
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use parameter `limit` in forward filling missing values with replace `False` to missing values and last replace `NaN`s to `False`:

```
y.A = y.A.replace(False, np.nan).ffill(limit=2).fillna(False)
print (y)
      A
0  False
1  False
2  False
3   True
4   True
5   True
6   True
7   True
8  False
9  False
```

Another idea with [`Rolling.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) and `any` for test at least one `True` per window:

```
y.A = y.A.rolling(3, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x.any()).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Nice one man! Didn't know `ffill` takes in `limit` param also. +1.